# How to set bind values to NULL with Firebird's jaybird JDBC driver?

Tags: java, jdbc, firebird, jaybird

I'm running into a bit of a situation in corner cases when binding `null` to a `PreparedStatement` with Firebird's jaybird JDBC driver. Here's a sample statement:

```
Class.forName("org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver");

// Observe the "local" in the connection string!
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:firebirdsql:local:C:/data/firebird/test.db", "TEST", "TEST");

// With this connection, I'm not able to reproduce the issue:
Connection con1 = DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:firebirdsql:localhost:C:/data/firebird/test.db", "TEST", "TEST");

PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(
  "SELECT cast(? as varchar(1)) FROM rdb$database");
stmt.setObject(1, null);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
rs.next();
System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
System.out.println(rs.wasNull());
```

The output of the above program is

```
>
> false
```

The first line being an empty string. It really should be

```
> null
> true
```

Changing this line ...

```
stmt.setObject(1, null);
```

... into any of these lines ...

```
stmt.setString(1, null);
stmt.setNull(1, Types.VARCHAR);
```

... doesn't help either. A workaround is to inline `null` literals in SQL statements, instead of binding them to the prepared statement. What am I missing?

**Details:**

- Database: Firebird WI-V2.5.1.26351
- JDBC driver: jaybird-2.2.0
- Java version: JDK 1.6.0_24
- OS: Windows 7 x64
- JDBC Connection String: See above.

Comment: As the answer below (and my own attempt at reproducing) show that Jaybird works as expected, it might be good to include additional information: full Firebird version, Java version, OS platform and the JDBC connection string used (or if you are using a DataSource: its full set of properties). If you have a working reproduction program and database you can also file a ticket at http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/ and I will take a look

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Thanks for your hints. How do I get the "full Firebird version"? I don't know how to use the [Service API](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq223/), whereas `rdb$get_context('SYSTEM', 'ENGINE_VERSION')` returns 2.5.1. The rest of the information has been added to the question

Comment: `DatabaseMetaData.getDatabaseProductVersion()` should return the full version

Comment: OK, but I'm able to narrow it down to my usage of the connection string. I'll update the question accordingly

Comment: Looks like a bug in the native part. Is there a specific reason you need the Type 2 (native) driver?

Comment: There's no specific reason, I can easily switch to the other URL type. I'm running integration tests for the upcoming integration of [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) with Firebird. This was the first connection URL I tried, which worked... Should I file a ticket for this issue?

Comment: I already created a ticket: http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/JDBC-271

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this is a bug in the JDBC driver:

http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/JDBC-271

It only appears when using this sort of connection URL:

```
// Observe the "local" in the connection string!
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:firebirdsql:local:C:/data/firebird/test.db", "TEST", "TEST");
```

Not with this sort:

```
// With this connection, I'm not able to reproduce the issue:
Connection con1 = DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:firebirdsql:localhost:C:/data/firebird/test.db", "TEST", "TEST");
```

Comment: It also occurs with jdbc:firebirdsql:native://localhost/D:/data/DB/testdatabase.fdb

Comment: It looks like it is only a problem when the parameter is part of the `select` column list, it correctly works as `null` when it is part of the `where`-condition or an `insert`-statement etc

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: My integration tests indicate something else. The problem really seems to be related to the `CAST(? as xxx)` operation. If `CAST` is used in `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statements, similar problems appear with any data type. I have also commented this on [JDBC-271](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/JDBC-271)

Comment: Bug will be fixed in Jaybird 2.2.1 and 2.3

Answer (score 3):

I can't reproduce the issue on *Jaybird 2.2.0* and *Firebird 2.1.3 (32-bit)* on *Windows 7 x64*. 
Copy pasting the source code and running it produces exactly the expected output.

Screenshot attached just in case:

[image]

**UPDATE**

Tested on *Jaybird 2.2.0* & *Firebird 2.5.1 (32bit)* on *Windows XP*, still cannot reproduce the issue -> Exact same output as expected.

Comment: Tested on jaybird 2.2.0 & firebird 2.5.1 (32bit) on Windows XP, still cannot reproduce the issue -> Exact same output as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Apparently, this is a bug in the JDBC driver: http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/JDBC-271